# Can function expression be used in forEach method?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, object, foreach

Here's my example of code:

```js
let arr = [18, 23, 44, 50];
let obj = {
    name: 'Kate',
};
arr.forEach(let func = function(value) {
    console.log(`${this.name} is ${value} years old`);
}, obj); //SyntaxError
```

So, it looks like we can use in `forEach()` method only function declaration and arrow function. Am I right or just missing something?

Comment: Check forEach syntax here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Comment: I think you are trying to bind your obj like `function printUser(value) {
    console.log(this.name+' is '+value+' years old');
}

arr.forEach(printUser.bind(obj));`

Comment: `only function declaration` .. a function declared in expression context (eg. to the right of a `=` sign, inside `()` etc.) is a function expression. So **ONLY** function expressions can be used inside `forEach()` if you are writing a function literal (instead of a variable or function name) because the moment you put a function inside `()` it becomes an expression

Comment: @slebetman _"a function declared in expression context (eg. to the right of a = sign, **inside () etc.**) is a function expression..."_ I can't agree with the part about `()`. I've just checked [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function#syntax). There's only one variant of function expression syntax

Comment: May I ask, is there a reason why you're looking to do this? Or is it just out of interest?

Comment: [The `let func =` is not part of the function expression](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69395145/1048572).

Answer (score 0):

Using `let`, `var`, or `const` where a callback function is expected is the `SyntaxError`. You could drop `let` and the code will run fine or you could declare the function outside of [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and call it within `forEach` as follows:

```js
let func = function(value) {
    console.log(`${this.name} is ${value} years old`);
};
arr.forEach(func, obj);
```

---

In the code below, I show the original code you provided without the `let` keyword in the `forEach` call to show that it works. I also added the suggested function declaration and the corresponding `forEach` call.

```js
let arr = [18, 23, 44, 50];
let obj = {
  name: 'Kate',
};

console.log('\tfunc');
arr.forEach(func = function(value) {
  console.log(`${this.name} is ${value} years old`);
}, obj);

console.log('\tfunc2');
let func2 = function(value) {
  console.log(`${this.name} is ${value} years old`);
};
arr.forEach(func2, obj);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use it without the assignment. The name (`func`) is optional.

```js
let arr = [18, 23, 44, 50];
let obj = {
    name: 'Kate',
};
arr.forEach(function func(value) {
    console.log(`${this.name} is ${value} years old`);
}, obj);
```